# Pop up window before executing js

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code

```
onclick='deleteTable("mytablename")'
```

Is there any way I can put a warning pop up ( you are deleting "mytablename" ) before the script is executed.

Thanks

Comment: Put this all thing in js function and function first check for warning and then call deletetable.. something like if(confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete'){deleteTable(..)}

Answer (score 0):

Use confirm for ask for the user if is sure of deleting:

```
$result = confirm('are you sure of deleting a table?');

if($result){
//execute the js code because the user selected yes
}else{
return; //exit
}
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8udtfsoh/